# Can't Check in folder recursively in SourceOffsite

Tags: version-control, sos

I am trying to check in a folder which contains few more folders inside it. How do I check them in recursively using SourceOffsite? If I select a parent folder, only the files gets checked in.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When in the AddFiles dialog, triggered from the client, select the folder you want to add, don't select single files from the list. click ok. on the next screen (comment) you will have a "recursive" checkBox [nice place to hide it]. check it and it will import all folders and files under your main one.

sourceOffSite version 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen this behavior too, so I'm guessing it's a bug.  It doesn't happen all the time for us.  We use SOS infrequently so we haven't escalated it to them.  Perhaps they have an update or a patch?

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you haven't selecte the option to process recursively?  Hold the shift key and right-click the node you and keep holding the shift key and select check-in.  This should bring you to a dialog where it lets you pick to act recursively, and, by the way, to only show the dialog when the shift key is down, which I tend to turn off.